# How to get multiple text entries and send them as an email?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, input, send

i'm trying to accomplish something here is my situation

I have an app which has:

Contact.xml : This layout has 6 Different text entries for Name, Email, Phone, Date, Time        Etc. plus 3 radio buttons (for Morning, Afternoon, Evening)[all 3 can be picked] All these need to be put in an email from the app and sent to my inbox. They all have different text inputs boxes.
so like this

```
Name    ___________
Email   ___________
Date    ___________
Date    ___________
Time    ___________

And Checkboxed selecting which time of the day
[Send]
```

Send is a button and lines are text input fields

What i need is to get all them and separate them with commas and send them via email. How would i do this. ( all i know is you have to do it by intent) . After clicking the send button i want a pop up to come up and select which mail client u want to use (dependent on what client app you installed [Gmail, Hotmail, yahoo Etc])

apologies is this has been asked before i just could not find one with my different text entries.

Thanks so much in advanced

Comment: i think i have pretty much solved the intent part and sending the email but to get the input fields all in one i have no idea. help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This code may solve your problem

        package com.example.intentex;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.sql.Date;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            TextView name1;
            EditText name;
            EditText email;
            TextView date1;
            EditText date;
            TextView time1;
            EditText time;
            Button button;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);
                final EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email1);
                final EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
                TextView date1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date1);
                final EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
                TextView time1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time1);
                final EditText time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
                Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       String myname = name.getText().toString();
                       String myemail = email.getText().toString();
                       String mydate = date.getText().toString();
                       String mytime = time.getText().toString();
                        String emailAddressList[] = {"emailAddres"};
                       String mycontent = myname + "," + myemail + "," + mydate + ","+ mytime;
                        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        email.setType("plain/text");
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mycontent);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Select Sender:"));


                    }
                });






            }


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: how would i get the check on/off for check boxes to the email? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the  text from the edittexts, use the getText() method.

In your activity or fragment onCreate, you will have some code that binds the views.

```
e.g. myInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myInputEditText);
```

(Make the myInput variable a field if it is not already).

So in the onclick of your button, you can access those views.

```
onClick(View view){
 String myInputText = myInput.getText().toString();
 String myPhoneNumber = myPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
 etc etc

//combing strings.
//there are more elegant ways to join strings if you have quite
//a few to join
String finalData = myInputText + "," + myPhoneNumber;

//you have this already
Intent emailIntent = new Intent......
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, finalData);
//start intent
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will investigate further and try this tomorrow as its nearly 2am here.

Comment: how would i get the check on/off for check boxes to the email? thanks

Comment: boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();